# TypeError: cannot read property '0' of undefined nodejs request http

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js, require

I'm trying to extend my Discord Bot with different commands which retrieves a JSON from an API. It worked for the first few like:

```
case 'results':
                request('http://ergast.com/api/f1/'+args[2]+'/'+args[3]+'/results.json', (error, response, body) => {
                    if(error) {msg.reply(error); }
                    const temp = JSON.parse(body);
                    let answer = '';
                    try {
                        for(var i = 0; i < temp.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0].Results.length; i++) {
                            answer += (i+1)+'. ' 
                                + temp.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0].Results[i].Driver.givenName +' '
                                + temp.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0].Results[i].Driver.familyName + ', ' 
                                + temp.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0].Results[i].Constructor.name + '\n';
                        }
                    }catch(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        answer = 'Choose earlier race, no results in yet';
                    }   
                    msg.reply(answer);
                });
                break;
```

So that was working, nice. When I try to get other values from another API-call (Driver Standings for f1 seasons), I'm running into following logs on my Heroku Deployed Discordbot:

```
2021-10-22T13:35:57.470709+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    2021-10-22T13:35:57.470710+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Request._callback (/app/index.js:254:73)
    2021-10-22T13:35:57.470710+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Request.self.callback (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    2021-10-22T13:35:57.470710+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Request.emit (events.js:400:28)
    2021-10-22T13:35:57.470711+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Request.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    2021-10-22T13:35:57.470711+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Request.emit (events.js:400:28)
    2021-10-22T13:35:57.470711+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
        2021-10-22T13:35:57.470712+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:519:28)
        2021-10-22T13:35:57.470712+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)
        2021-10-22T13:35:57.470712+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at endReadableNT 
(internal/streams/readable.js:1334:12)
        2021-10-22T13:35:57.470713+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections 

(internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

My faulty code is following, where the logs say, that Standingslist(?) is undefined, even though it can be seen in the http response?
Faulty code:

```
                case 'driverstandings':                 
                    request('http://ergast.com/api/f1/'+args[2]+'/driverStandings.json', (error, response, body) => {
                    if(error) {msg.reply(error); }
                    const temp = JSON.parse(body);
                    let answer = 'Season: ' + temp.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsList[0].round;
                    try {
                        for(var i = 0; i < temp.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsList[0].DriverStandings.length; i++) {
                            answer += (i+1)+'. ' 
                                + temp.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsList[0].DriverStandings[i].Driver.givenName +' '
                                + temp.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsList[0].DriverStandings[i].Driver.familyName + ', ' 
                                + temp.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsList[0].DriverStandings[i].points +' points, wins: '
                                + temp.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsList[0].DriverStandings[i].wins +'\n';
                        }
                    }catch(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        answer = 'No entries';
                    }   
                    msg.reply(answer);
                });
                break;
```

Syntax-wise, I just can't figure out my error.

The JSON is structured as following: [json structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HlzJ.png)

API for json is: [JSON](http://ergast.com/api/f1/2021/driverStandings.json)

Comment: Problems caused by typos will most likely be closed because they are very unlikely to help future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didnt tried you code, bit it seems it should be Standingslists and not Standingslist.
Can you try it?

Br
Patrick

Comment: Yes, just figured that out as well. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: Your welcome... happens to me a lot... most of nullpointer exceptions are from typos or wrong size of array :) Have  a nice weekend

Comment: Haha yeah I figured it should be something like that, Syntax looked fine to me. Just left of for some hours and yeah - magicigally found the error ;D
You too, enjoy it!:)

Answer (score 0):

typo -> StandingList instead of StandingsList